# How to convert filemode to int?

Tags: go, formatting, int, file-permissions

Sample code:

```
func main() {
    p, _ := os.Open(os.Args[1])
    m, _ := p.Stat()
    println(m.Mode().Perm())
}
```

File has mode `0775` (`-rwxrwxr-x`). Running it like:

> ./main main

Prints `509`

And second:

```
func main() {
    p, _ := os.Open(os.Args[1])
    m, _ := p.Stat()
    println(m.Mode().Perm().String())
}
```

This code prints `-rwxrwxr-x`.

How I can get mode in format `0775`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The value `509` is the decimal (base 10) representation of the permission bits.

The form `0775` is the octal representation (base 8). You can print a number in octal representation using the `%o` verb:

```
perm := 509
fmt.Printf("%o", perm)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/AtpmdVgz6q)):

```
775
```

If you want the output to be 4 digits (with a leading `0` in this case), use the format string `"%04o"`:

```
fmt.Printf("%04o", perm) // Output: 0775
```